# Exercise with absolute maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus

Find the absolute maximum and minimum of the function $\ f(x,y,z)= \ x^2+\ y^2+\ z^2 $ on the set $ \{(x,y,z): x^2=z^2+1 \}$.

**My solution and question:** To find the critical points I used the formula

$ L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)+\lambda(g(x,y,z))$

which in my case turns out to be

$L(x,y,z,\lambda)=x^2+y^2+z^2+\lambda(x^2-z^2-1)$ hence deriving

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
2x+2x\lambda=0 \\
2y=0 \\
2z-2z\lambda=0 \\
x^2-z^2-1=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
doing all the steps you get to have  \begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\lambda=-1\\
y=0\\
z=0\\
x=\pm 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So I get critical points $\;(-1,0,0)\;$ e $\; (1,0,0)\;$

going to replace in the function $\;f(x,y,z)\;$ we get for both points the value $1.$

So are both points of maximum?And what is the minimum?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative

$$f(x,y,z)= \ x^2+\ y^2+\ z^2 \land x^2=z^2+1 \implies g(y,z)=y^2+2z^2+1$$

and

- $g_y=2y=0$
- $g_z=4z=0$

therefore according to your derivation critical points are $(\pm 1,0,0)$.

To conclude note that since

$$g(y,z)=y^2+2z^2+1\ge 1$$

and

$$g(y,z)=1 \iff y=z=0$$

both points are point of global minimum.

Comment: The first part is clear to me to find the critical points but the second one is not. Why do you set  $g(y,z)=y^2+2z^2+1\ge 1$ ? And then can there be two points of absolute minimum?

Comment: @cloe $y^2+2z^2$ is a sum of square and therefore $y^2+2z^2\ge 0$ that is $y^2+2z^2+1\ge 1$ and $y^2+2z^2+1= 1\iff y=z=0$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y,z)=1+2z^{2}+y^{2}\geq 1$ and $f(x,y,z)=1$ when $y=z=0$ and $x=1$ so the minimum value is $1$. You are not asked to find the critical points, so this is a complete answer. The function is not bounded so sup is $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

To classify if it is a max/min point, calculate the [bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) matrix:
$$\bar{H}=\begin{vmatrix}0&\phi_x&\phi_y&\phi_z\\ \phi_x&L_{xx}&L_{xy}&L_{xz}\\ \phi_y&L_{yx}&L_{yy}&L_{yz}\\
\phi_z&L_{zx}&L_{zy}&L_{zz}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}0&2x&0&-2z\\ 2x&2+\lambda&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2\\
-2z&0&2&2-2\lambda\end{vmatrix},$$
where $\phi(x,y,z)=x^2-z^2-1$.
Minors:
$$\begin{align}\bar{H}_1&=\begin{vmatrix}0&2x\\ 2x&2+\lambda\end{vmatrix}=-4x^2<0; \\
\bar{H}_2&=0;\\
\bar{H}_3&=-16x^2<0.\end{align}$$
This is the condition for minimum. Hence, the found points are local minimum points.

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether it is the minimum or maximum, there is a systematic method, but very complicated. However for your question, we note that when $|z|$ is sufficiently large, so is $|x|$ then $f$. Therefore $f$ is unbounded above, i.e. has no maximum. Then both of your point only could be of minimum. Since 
$$
f(x,y,z) = y^2 +2z^2 +1\geqslant 1
$$
on the set, and clearly $f(\pm 1,0,0)=1$, thus the points are minimum points.